# Strange Bot Traffic in Google Analytics and the Mystery of the Made-up URLs

Tags: wordpress, bots, rss, mailchimp

So, I've started working for a company, lets call it XYZ, doing marketing in general and helping form their SEO strategy and get a handle on how well their website is performing. They have a Wordpress website that is managed by an outside firm, and a Mailchimp newsletter that goes out monthly.

The direct traffic in Google Analytics is super high. I found that they had a Shopify store at one point, and I'm pretty sure it wasn't properly done and was causing the GA tag to fire wrong, resulting in a lot of self-referrals.

Our newsletter went out recently, and we saw a spike in traffic. Much more traffic than the Mailchimp Analytics can account for. Digging into the analytics, it looks like bot traffic. Quincy, Washington, Cheyenne, Wyoming and others. We aren't near these areas nor do we do business in these areas, and each city had a high number of hits, more than is normal. So probably bots, so far so good.

Here is the mystery I am trying to solve, and I hope I can get this explained correctly.

I checked the analytics after our most recent newsletter (an rss feed type with a template maid in Mailchimp) I saw a spike in traffic, which was the bot traffic I mentioned earlier. This bot traffic hit a webpage that doesn't exist on our domain. as an example

xyz.com/5-things-for-a-list-article/Here

The traffic was all trying to get to a URL structured like the one above.

The actual URL for the post would look like this in the example

xyz.com/5-things-for-a-list-article/

The extra word at the end of the traffic hitting a 404 page is the first word from the article.

The link in the newsletter shows a snippet of the post.

Digging into the history of the site and the newsletter this happens, (albeit not as much as this most recent time and not all the time) with a lot of posts that are shared in the newsletter. I look at the day the newsletter goes out, there is some amount of traffic to the 404 page, and the link path is the actual URL to the post, but with the first word of the article tacked on the end.

What is happening here? Are bots crawling the newsletter and getting the URL links wrong?

I will also add that our website is a WordPress install that uses the DIVI theme or plugin or whatever it is. At first I thought it was to blame because the URL with the high surge of traffic was going to a custom post type created by DIVI, but regular posts have had it happen as well. THe only connection I have found so far is the bots hit a 404 page that has the URL of an item in the RSS feed to our newsletter.

Anyone that can shed some light, I would greatly appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is an error in the Mailchimp template, where there is no space between the url and the first word in the source of the email so "`https://example.com/page/` abc ..." is seen in email clients as "`https://example.com/page/abc` ..."

It would have helped if you had shown the example source from the email and the code used to construct the URL, as I've had to go for a best guess at reverse engineering the likely cause.

Comment: So the MailChimp email is populated by rss.

*|Rssitems:|*
*|Rssitem:title|*
*|Rssitem:content|*
*|End:rssitems|*

I don't have access to code, and I'm new to rss so I don't know how to find more info on how he has implemented it.

The traffic to the weird link was 3 times the amount of total clicks reported by MailChimp. All showing as direct and from just a handful of cities I think are known for bot traffic.
For that specific link, 7 clicks are reported on MailChimp, but analytics says over three hundred hit the weird link.
I appreciate you trying to help me make sense of this.

Comment: I do think you are on to something about the space I the URL, but looking back a the analytics only two of the five links got hits on weird urls, one got the bulk (299) the other only got 2.

Comment: Can you provide the source from one of the actual emails that has been sent?

Comment: Maybe when I go back to work after the holidays. I looked at the code myself and it seems fine. MailChimp and google support both told me to talk to the web developer as they couldn't see a problem. Thing is the "web developer" is just a guy that makes poorly implemented WordPress sites. He's already told me he doesn't know anything about the bot traffic and he is not interested in figuring it out.